# How to assign module name to a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module

I would like to dynamically let the user chose which body of data he/she would like to work with. To do this, after the user identifies their "corpus" of choice, I must import the appropriate corpus. (I am running on Python 2.7.3)

```
corpora_ls = ["gutenberg","inaugural","movie_reviews","state_union"]
import_validation = False

while not import_validation:
    print "Corpora Options: \"gutenberg\", \"inaugural\", \"movie_reviews\", \"state_union\"."
    import_option = str(raw_input("What corpus would you like to import? "))

    if import_option in corpora_ls:
        import_validation = True

        if import_option == "gutenberg":
            fname = "gutenberg"
            from nltk.corpus import gutenberg as DATA
        elif import_option == "inaugural":
            fname = "inaugural"
            from nltk.corpus import inaugural as DATA
        elif import_option == "movie_reviews":
            fname = "movie_reviews"
            from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews as DATA
        elif import_option == "state_union":
            fname = "state_union"
            from nltk.corpus import state_union as DATA
    else:
        print "Please enter one of the available corpora as listed.\n"
```

Frankly, this code looks cumbersome to me. I would like to be able to simply say something to the effect of:

```
if import_option == "gutenberg":
    fname = "gutenberg"
elif import_option == "inaugural":
    fname = "inaugural"

   etc....

from nltk.corpus import import_option as DATA
```

rather than having to do a separate `from nltk.corpus...etc.` for every `if/elif`

Is something like this possible?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have a look at [`importlib.import_module`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) and/or the [`__import__` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can use `getattr`:

```
import nltk.corpus
corpus_data = getattr(nltk.corpus, corpus_name)
```

Comment: @Jared: I guess I assumed it was a module, which was an incorrect assumption. I now see that it was just a property of the `nltk.corpus` module. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. The above works perfectly.